# Prints the number of shapes of a binary Tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree, nodes

I am trying to figure out why my code does not work for returning the `shapes` a `binary tree` can take

```
public static long shapes (int n) {
if (n == 0) return 1;
if (n == 1) return 1;
long result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    result = result + shapes(i-1)*shapes(n-i);
    }
return result
}
```

this should follow the rules of 
`L(0) = 1` 
`L(1) = L(0)*L(0) = 1` 
`L(2) = L(0)*L(1) + L(1)*L(0) = 1 + 1 = 2` 
`L(3) = L(0)*L(2) + L(1)*L(1) + L(2)*L(0) = 2 + 1 + 2 = 5`

I am thinking it has to do with me calling `shapes(i-1)` but I am not so sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were most likely getting a *stack overflow error* based on the `shapes(n-i)`.  n-i when i is 0 would be shapes(n).  This would again go through the for loop and call shapes(n-i) or shapes(n) in an infinite loop.

*Note: After n > 35 the result overflows a long*

```
    public static long shapes(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0) return 1;
        if (n == 1) return 1;
        long result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            result = result + shapes(i) * shapes(n - i - 1);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

results are:

> ```
> shapes 0 = 1
> shapes 1 = 1
> shapes 2 = 2
> shapes 3 = 5
> shapes 4 = 14
> shapes 5 = 42
> shapes 6 = 132
> shapes 7 = 429
> shapes 8 = 1430
> shapes 9 = 4862
> ```

As Richard Plunkett points out the solution has serious performance issues.  One strategy to solve this issue when you are repeating the same calculation as in this case is to store away previous results and then look them up instead of recalculating them.  The solution below takes advantage of this performance enhancement.

```
    private static Dictionary<int, System.Numerics.BigInteger> results = 
        new Dictionary<int, System.Numerics.BigInteger>();

    public static System.Numerics.BigInteger shapes(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0) return 1;
        if (n == 1) return 1;
        System.Numerics.BigInteger result = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            System.Numerics.BigInteger left = 0;
            System.Numerics.BigInteger right = 0;
            if (!results.ContainsKey(i - 1))
            {
                left = shapes(i - 1);
                results[i - 1] = left;
            }
            else
            {
                left = results[i - 1];
            }

            if (!results.ContainsKey(n - i))
            {
                right = shapes(n - i);
                results[n - i] = right;
            }
            else
            {
                right = results[n - i];
            }

            result +=  left * right;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried calling that as well, I can't tell the error because my shell terminal won't show it.

Comment: I figured out all my errors until the point when I had to called shapes (n - i - 1), this was the tricky party for me, thank you. I understand how this recursion takes place now.

Comment: Now you need to learn dynamic programming, since this code wont terminate for even modestly sized n.